# Display Name insted of ID

Tags: c#, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two models which is connected by `Foreign Key` and in my View I want to display Name insted of `ID`
Here is my Servis action which is used to retrive data from `db`

```
 public ListaSveVM UcitajIzvjestaj()
        {
            var listaFromDb = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId);
            var listaM = new List<GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM>();

            foreach (var i in listaFromDb)
            {
                var novizv = new GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM();
                novizv.IzvjestajiGenerisaniId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId;
                novizv.KratkiNazivDefinicijeI = (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv;
                novizv.Naziv = i.Naziv;
                novizv.Opis = i.Opis;
                novizv.DatumKreiranja = i.DatumUnosa;
                novizv.DatumAzuriranja = i.DatumAzuriranja;
                novizv.IzvjestajXsdshemaiId = i.IzvjestajXsdshemaiId;               
                listaM.Add(novizv);
            }
            var lista = "";
            lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaM, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
            var listaVM = new ListaSveVM();
            listaVM.sve = lista;
            return listaVM;
        }
```

And In my View  I have datatable to display those data

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#tabela').dataTable({
            language: {
                buttons: {
                    copyTitle: 'Uspjeh',
                    copySuccess: {
                        _: '%d redova kopirano',
                        1: '1 red kopiran'
                    }
                },
                processing: "Upit se obrađuje...",
                search: "Pretraga&nbsp;:",
                lengthMenu: "_MENU_ redova",
                info: "Prikazano _START_  do _END_ od ukupno _TOTAL_ redova",
                infoEmpty: "Nema zapisa...",
                infoFiltered: "(filtrirano _MAX_ redova ukupno)",
                infoPostFix: "",
                loadingRecords: "Zapisi se učitavaju...",
                zeroRecords: "U tabeli je nula redova.",
                emptyTable: "Tabela je prazna!",
                   select: {
                    rows: {
                        _: "",
                        0: "",
                        1: ""
                    }
                },
                paginate: {
                    first: "Prvi",
                    previous: "<i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i>",
                    next: "<i class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i>",
                    last: "Posljednji"
                },
                aria: {
                     sortAscending: ": ",
                    sortDescending: ": "
                }
            },
            order: [[0, 'dsc']],
            data: @Html.Raw(@Model.sve),
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "IzvjestajiGenerisaniId",
                    "width": 20,
                    "className": 'dt-body-center'
                },

                { data: "KratkiNazivDefinicijeI" },
                { data: "IzvjestajXsdshemaiId" },
                { data: "Naziv" },
                { data: "Opis" },
                {
                    data: "DatumKreiranja",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return (moment(data).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "DatumAzuriranja",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return (moment(data).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
                    }
                },
            ]
        });   //kraj tabele

            var table = $('#tabela').DataTable();

            // Primjeni pretragu samo za odabrane kolone
            table.columns([1, 2, 3]).every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
     });
```

But it View it display ID and right now I want to convert this ID to Name. 
I try to put in my Model

```
[Display(Name = "NameOfXSDSchema")]
```

But this doesn work. 
[image]

**UPDATE**

I have two models

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IZ.Model.DBModels
{
    public partial class IzvjestajXsdshema
    {
        public IzvjestajXsdshema()
        {
            IzvjestajDefinicija = new HashSet<IzvjestajDefinicija>();
            IzvjestajiGenerisani = new HashSet<IzvjestajiGenerisani>();
        }

        public int IzvjestajXsdshemaiId { get; set; }
        public string Shema { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }
        public string HederXls { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajDefinicija> IzvjestajDefinicija { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajiGenerisani> IzvjestajiGenerisani { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IZ.Model.DBModels
{
    public partial class IzvjestajDefinicija
    {
        public IzvjestajDefinicija()
        {
            IzvjestajElementi = new HashSet<IzvjestajElementi>();
            IzvjestajiGenerisani = new HashSet<IzvjestajiGenerisani>();
        }

        public int IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajTipId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajXsdshemaiId { get; set; }
        public string KratkiNaziv { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }

        public virtual IzvjestajTip IzvjestajTip { get; set; }
        public virtual IzvjestajXsdshema IzvjestajXsdshemai { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajElementi> IzvjestajElementi { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajiGenerisani> IzvjestajiGenerisani { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And one ViewModels which I use to take data from it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace IZ.Model.VM
{
    public class GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM
    {
        public int IzvjestajiGenerisaniId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajXsdshemaiId { get; set; }
        public string KratkiNazivDefinicijeI { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public string Izvjestaj { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumOd { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumDo { get; set; }
        public string ImportedExcel { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumKreiranja { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }
        public string NazivXmlfajla { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And right now `IzvjestajXSDShemaId` is display ID in my `View` and I want to display Name (Schema in Model IzvjestajXSDShema) in View insted of `ID`

Comment: Allway try to provide a [*Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question contains very much irrelevant code, which makes understanding your question very hard. I cannot find the relevant part in your javascript code, and cannot figure out which field is the ID you want the name from.

Comment: `IzvjestajXsdshemaiId` ?

Comment: @MohammadDehghan I will try to edit my question to better understand .

Comment: @MohammadDehghan Yes, I want to dispay Name insted of ID in row.  SO I dont want to displa 1,2,3,4, I want to write  1STF, 2STR etc

Comment: @MohammadDehghan I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try to retrieve all your data from the database in one round (single query). In most cases, it is possible and very easy.

Add a `IzvjestajXSDShema` field to your view model, and change your code to:

```
var _context = new DbContext();
var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija
    .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
    .Select(i => new GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM()
    {
        IzvjestajiGenerisaniId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
        KratkiNazivDefinicijeI =
            (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
        Naziv = i.Naziv,
        Opis = i.Opis,
        DatumKreiranja = i.DatumUnosa,
        DatumAzuriranja = i.DatumAzuriranja,
        IzvjestajXsdshemaiId = i.IzvjestajXsdshemaiId,

        // Here we use navigation properties provided by your ORM to
        // bring the required field from other entity
        IzvjestajXSDShema = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema
    })
    .ToList();

var lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

There are a few things to note in the code above:

1. Do not call `.ToList()` until the end of your query. Calling `ToList()` will run the query and brings the data into memory. This usually brings more data than required.
2. Use [**Navigation Properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) to retrieve related data. EF produces required `JOIN` operations in the final query to optimally fetch the data you want.
3. Your view model should contain *all* the things you need to send to UI.

Comment: IzvjestajXSDShema = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema this line of code doesnt recognize Schema  `IzvjestajXSDShema`

Comment: @Xerror change it to whatever field you need to bring from that entity. I just used one of the fields you said you have in `IzvjestajXsdshema` entity.

Comment: @Xerror I also said at the beginning of the post that: "Add a IzvjestajXSDShema field to your view model".

Comment: You mean all property from `IzvjestajXSDShema` to add in my ViewModel ??

Comment: @Xerror Look at my point 3. Add all the fields that you need to display in UI.

Comment: Yes, I get it :) Thank you :D